# Carry extra info in error reponse

Tags: python, django, tastypie

What is best way to return extra data such as error code in error type response. #Method 1 does not carry extra info while #Method 2 doesnt work.

```
#method 1
ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpBadRequest('error')) #cant carry extra info


#method 2
class ErrorInfo(object):
    msg_id = ''
    msg_code = ''
    msg_content = ''

class Resource(Resource):
    ....
    def get_object_list(self, request):
        if ...:
            error_info = ErrorInfo()
            error_info.msg_id = 'rt'
            error_info.msg_code = 'rerer'
            obj  = {'objects': error_info}
            return self.create_response(request, obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps, you can use  ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpResquest([...], status=403))

Comment: Yes,works.                                                          raise ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpBadRequest([{'msg_id':'1','msg_code':'r4r'}], status=403))

Comment: status=403 is for "Forbidden". For bad request, use status=400. As you're using HttpBadRequest, it's 400 by default.